# CI needs forever to resolve Swift Package Manager dependencies for xcodebuild

Tags: ios, gitlab-ci, fastlane, swift-package-manager, fastlane-gym

For our Swift projects we only use the Swift Package Manager (SPM) and when we are running a job inside our GitLab pipeline, it can take forever to resolve those dependencies.

We use `fastlane gym` action, which basically does `xcodebuild` as you can see here:

```
Resolving Swift Package Manager dependencies...
$ xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -scheme X -project X.xcodeproj -configuration Release -scmProvider system
```

It took 10 minutes for 20 packages, I mean it doesn't sound like much, but feels like it and when you have to do this everytime we run a pipeline, this slows us down a lot.

So maybe someone can explain to me, why it needs to resolve package dependencies and how we could increase the speed doing it on our CI.